# Angular: inserir somente data no input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, formulário

No sistema existe um campo para inserir uma data. Quero bloquear o input para inserir somente os valores dd/mm/aaaa

```
<mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
<mat-label>Data citação</mat-label>                         
<input matInput  [matDatepicker]="datePickerCriacao" [max]="hoje"  (click)="datePickerCriacao.open()" id="dataCitacao" placeHolder="Data citação" [(ngModel)]="dataCitacao" name="dataCitacao" maxlength="10">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePickerCriacao"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #datePickerCriacao></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: tenta adicionar um type date ou number no input

Answer (score 0):

Você pode conseguir isso com a ajuda do [angular2-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask)

**Component**

```
public mask = {
    guide: true,
    showMask : true,
    mask: [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/',/\d/, /\d/,/\d/, /\d/]
 };
```

**Template**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [textMask]="mask" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Selecione uma data">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```